# Keystone.JS multiple partial folders and changing name

Tags: keystonejs

I have a few questions about the partial folder in the templates/views folder of keystone.js (using handlebars):

1) Is it possible to have multiple partials folders? (If yes, how do you do it?)

2) Can I change the name of the folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create subdirectories inside the *templates/views/partials* directory.

For example, you can create a directory *templates/views/partials/sub* and create a file **myPartial.hbs**, and then you can include it in another file like so:

```
{{> sub/myPartial }}
```

KeystoneJS will handle registration of **.hbs** files in the *templates/views/partials* directory and any subdirectories within it.

You can change the name of the **partials** directory in the *keystone.js* file in the root of your project.

Find the **'custom engine'** option passed to **keystone.init()** and change the value for **partialsDir**:

```
'custom engine': handlebars.create({
  layoutsDir: 'templates/views/layouts',
  partialsDir: 'templates/views/new-partials',
  defaultLayout: 'default',
  helpers: new require('./templates/views/helpers')(),
  extname: '.hbs',
}).engine,
```

You can also create multiple partials directories by using an array:

```
'custom engine': handlebars.create({
  layoutsDir: 'templates/views/layouts',
  partialsDir: ['templates/views/partials', 'templates/views/other-partials'],
  defaultLayout: 'default',
  helpers: new require('./templates/views/helpers')(),
  extname: '.hbs',
}).engine,
```

Comment: Hi,

thanks for the answer. That is of course a pity, because I am losing a lot of flexibility. Maybe I will have to use technologies like webpack after all.

Comment: I found out how to rename the **partials** directory and how to create multiple partials directories. I have updated my answer.